# Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. (Tensorflow 1.8)

Tags: tensorflow

I have a list of _EmbeddingColumn and want to convert it to a tensor. I call `tf.feature_column.input_layer` with error

> ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type 'collections._EmbeddingColumn'>)

Comment: A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help.

Comment: It seems a bug in pyspark.